# Separate implementation to a same class for iOS and Android in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am working on a Xamarin project in which a class needs to have a separate implementation in iOS and Android. I am thinking about have a `interface` in the Shared project and have its implementation in iOS and Android project. But I have no idea how to do that.

This is what I have tried so far, but the compiler throws me an error in the `callMe` method of MyPopup_iOS, *"No suitable method to override"*. And since I don't have any reference to the **MyPopup_iOS.cs** file in the shared project, how do I call this method?

**File: MyPopup.cs in MyProject**

```
public interface MyPopup
{
    void callMe();
}
```

**File MyPopup_IOS in MyProject.iOS**

```
public class MyPopup_IOS : MyPopup
{
    public override void callMe()
    {
    }       
}
```

Comment: override is for methods declared in a base class, not an interface.  I think you either want to look at using DI, or the Bait and Switch pattern: http://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/

Answer (score 1):

1) Change interface MyPopup to abstract class

```
public abstract class MyPopup
{
    void callMe();
}
```

2) Change void CallMe() to abstract

```
public abstract void CallMe ();
```

3) In your platform specific class override that method

```
public class MyPopup_IOS : MyPopup
{
    public override void callMe()
    {
    }       
}
```

4) Now you can call that method from base class. It will trigger platform specific implementation

```
public abstract class MyPopup
{
    public abstract void callMe();
    void doWork() {
       callMe();
     }
 }
```